# Como posso escrever "nada posso dizer a você" usando pronome?

Tags: gramática

Como posso escrever "nada posso dizer a você" usando pronome?

Pode ser "Nada posso dize-lhe"? 
Ou "Nada posso te dizer"?

Ou outra coiza? Quais formas posso escrever esta sentença?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, o pronome dativo que corresponde a *você* é *lhe*, não *te*.

Em segundo, a forma mais natural é com a frase na negativa. Aqui, há duas hipóteses de colocação do pronome clítico *lhe*: ou associado ao domínio infinitivo, posposto ao verbo (ênclise):

> Não posso dizer-lhe nada.

Ou associado ao verbo finito *poder* (subida do clítico). A subida do clítico para o verbo finito é possível com um conjunto limitado de verbos auxiliares e semi-auxiliares, nos quais se inclui *poder*. Mas nesse caso, tratando-se de uma oração negativa, a próclise é obrigatória (é impossível a oração **não posso-lhe dizer nada*):

> Não lhe posso dizer nada.

Com *nada* a começar a frase, os padrões de colocação do pronome são os mesmos, já que *nada* também força a próclise:

> Nada lhe posso dizer.
>   Nada posso dizer-lhe.

Na variedade brasileira é ainda possível uma próclise sem subida do clítico:

> Não posso lhe dizer nada. [apenas PB]